# Decimal format in Regular Expression

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2005, windows

In winforms, I use Regular expression to check decimal format. Please check whether my format is correct or not.

For example

```
123456.1234 

"^{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}$"
```

Is there any better format?

Actually I just wanna get 6 numeric and 4 decimal points only. How to format it?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't `^\d+(\.\d)?$` be better?

This check for a number at the start of the string, then maybe a `.` followed by another number.

Comment: +1 Would you want to add a quantifier to match more than number in the decimal portion?

Comment: Actually I just wanna get 6 numeric and 4 decimal points only. How to do it?

Comment: `^\d{6}\.\d{4}$`. This will only work for exactly 6 numbers, then a `.` and then finally 4 numbers.

Comment: Do you want to support + or - sign symbols?

Comment: @mads.ohm, I can just put 1 digit or 1 decimal only, no more cannot. I check isMatch in textbox's keypress event.

Comment: @soclose, I do not know how isMatch works, but I have tried inputting the RegEx into an online regular expression interpreter and here is the answer: http://regexr.com?2u1ht